# The returned data is partially missing in ASP.NET Web API GET method

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, postman, asp.net-core-webapi

I have some trouble with my ASP.NET Web API application with returned data.

I have 2 models, Province-to-District as One-to-Many relationships. I use Eager Loading following [a tutorial from Microsoft Website](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/read-related-data?view=aspnetcore-3.0)

Here is my `Province.cs` model

```
[Table("province")]
public class Province
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("displayName")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [Column("code")]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Code { get; set; }

    // FKs
    public virtual ICollection<District> Districts { get; set; }
}
```

My `District.cs` model

```
[Table("district")]
public class District
{
    [Key]
    [Column("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Column("displayName")]
    public string DisplayName { get; set; }

    [Column("prefix")]
    public string Prefix { get; set; }

    [Column("provinceId")]
    public int ProvinceId { get; set; }

    // FKs
    public virtual Province Province { get; set; }
}
```

At my `LocationController.cs`

```
public async Task<ActionResult<IEnumerable<Province>>> GetProvince([FromQuery] Province _province)
{
    // Eager Loading
    return await _context.province.Include(p => p.Districts).Where(p => p.Id == _province.Id).ToListAsync();
}
```

When I call `https://localhost:44346/api/province?id=1` or with any `id` existed in my database. Both Postman and all my browsers (MS Edge, Chrome...) return only one part of a JSONArray. Look likes this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "displayName": "Hồ Chí Minh",
        "code": "SG",
        "districts": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "displayName": "Bình Chánh",
                "prefix": "Huyện",
                "provinceId": 1
```

That's it. Only 11 lines of data. It doesn't even match the JSON format.

My expected return must be:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "displayName": "Hồ Chí Minh",
        "code": "SG",
        "districts": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "displayName": "Bình Chánh",
                "prefix": "Huyện",
                "provinceId": 1
            },
            {
                ...
            },...
    },...
]
```

Or at least, the right format of JSON.

My previous 2 APIs get all data of each table work fine.

What I'm missing here? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a model and return it instead of your entities.

This is happening because of self reference loop.

If you are using `Newtonsoft.Json` you can ignore it in startup.cs

```
services.AddMvc()
     .AddJsonOptions(options =>
     {
         options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
     })
```

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot!